# FETCH throwing exception java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

Whenever I add this line of code it always throw the exception

```
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Complete code:

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME, EMPLOYEES.EMAIL,
    EMPLOYEES.PHONE_NUMBER, EMPLOYEES.HIRE_DATE, EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID,
    EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID, EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID, EMPLOYEES.SALARY,
    JOBS.JOB_ID, JOBS.JOB_TITLE, DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID,
    DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME, DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID, M.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    M.FIRST_NAME
    || ' '
    || M.LAST_NAME AS MANAGER_NAME 
FROM 
    EMPLOYEES 
INNER JOIN 
    JOBS ON EMPLOYEES.JOB_ID = JOBS.JOB_ID 
INNER JOIN  
    DEPARTMENTS ON EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID 
INNER JOIN  
    EMPLOYEES M ON DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID = M.EMPLOYEE_ID 
ORDER BY 
    EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID ASC
```

I want to display data from multiple tables in my site and limit it only to ten output but it always throw the exception. What should I do? I've tried adding aliases but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is:

According to The Oracle 12c documentation about FETCH:

> If the select list contains columns with identical names and you
>   specify the row_limiting_clause, then an ORA-00918 error occurs. This
>   error occurs whether the identically named columns are in the same
>   table or in different tables. You can work around this issue by
>   specifying unique column aliases for the identically named columns.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Give alias to duplicate names

```
M.FIRST_NAME as "Manager name"
```

Or without `as`

```
DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID "Department ID",
```